# Regarding Convolution Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, keras

I have some question in CNN.

1. Why should we add the 4th dimension eg. (1, 300, 300, 3) in `model.predict()` to the input image? What is the need for that 4th dimesnion?
2. Shall we use image with RGBA values i.e., input_shape = (300, 300, 4) in `keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (300, 300, 4))`?
   I tried this but it says error: `InvalidArgumentError : input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 4 vs 3`. What should I do for images with RGBA values? I tried by converting it into RGB at `model.predict()` stage and it works fine.
   Is there any way to use without converting.

Edit:
Github link of entire code is below: https://github.com/beingmechon/rps_classification/blob/master/RPS_classification.ipynb

Comment: Can you post a larger portion of your code? It's hard to tell from context.

Comment: @StanShunpike Hello, I posted the GitHub link of the entire code kindly check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the fourth dimension of 3 indicates a color image encodes as RGB or similar. You have three bytes for each color. It is the case with your code.

What to do with RGBA depends on what kind of a model you're building. If you're working one that's designed to work with RGB, then I'd convert your RGBA into RGB, maybe by ignoring the alpha channel. The fourth bytt is simply opaqueness, drop it.

Another way would be to modify your net to intake RGBA. You could try simply changing the dimensions of layers. You can't simply declare that the input is 4 bytes. You'd have to modify the net to be able to multiply the matrix or convolve it, so that the model at least compiles. Even that doesn't guarantee it will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

(1,300,300,3) means 1 image of 300 height by 300 width with 3 channels. The 0th dimension is batch size, so if you want to predict many images at once, concatenate them along the 0th axis. RGBA would be 4 channels, grayscale would be 1 channel. If the weights were trained on 3 channel RGB, you need to predict on 3 channel RGB images, or the result can't be expected to perform correctly. Same goes if you input RGB when it was trained on BGR. If the shape is incorrect you'll get an error (as you experienced for 4 channel input). Prediction inputs need to be preprocessed as similarly to training inputs as possible. However, popping the alpha channel off of an RGBA is acceptable since that's quite literally just an RGB left over. Hope that helps!